# Google reCaptcha verification fails with invalid response

Tags: node.js, recaptcha, verify

I am trying to verify the captcha using `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify`
But I am getting issue with validating it. I am passing secret and response in query string as well, and also in body, tried with both approach.

Please find the code below:

```
let post_data = {
        secret: process.env.RECAPTCHA_LEGACY_IOS,
        response: token
      };
 
 let data = await axios.post(`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?`,post_data);
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Please check if there is an input for `console.log(process.env.RECAPTCHA_LEGACY_IOS)` in order to verify if there is a value for the environment variable `RECAPTCHA_LEGACY_IOS`. If a value exists, it should be printed to the console.